# c# sqldataadapter params in using

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldataadapter

is there any option to initialize sqldataadapter with params ? I'm starting it with using so there's no option to use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue .

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from smthg where kh_Symbol = '" + khSymbol + "'", cn,))
                {}
```

I want to take of sql statement to the configuration file, but I want to kh_Symbol be in param like this:

```
select * from smthg where kh_Symbol = '@param'
```

I don't know how to do it in USING.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting something you have to use  [`SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var p = dap.SelectCommand.Parameters;
p.AddWithValue("@kh_Symbol", khSymbol);
```

Comment: but how to do it in USING?

Comment: hmm.. tried but it looks like it doesn't work - this parametr isn't working. full code:

`code`                     using (SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from smthg where kh_Symbol = '@param'",cn))
                    {
                        var p = dap.SelectCommand.Parameters;
                        p.AddWithValue("@kh_Symbol", khSymbol);
                        dtpk.Clear();
                        dap.Fill(dtpk);